# how to to automaticly get a multiple form

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a HTML form, it's meant to create step to pass on a game and I want to be able to enter a number and when for example I enter 5 it instantly show me 5 form to fill and create new step but when I try it doesn't appear how can I do please?

```php
<h3>Insertion des étape :</h3>

<form action="InsertionEtape.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    <br>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $_GET['quantity']; $i++) {
       ?>
        <h5>Nom de l'étape</h5>
        <input type="text" name="NomEtape" size="40" maxlength="40">
        <br>

        <h5> Description de l'étape </h5>
        <textarea name="DescriptionEtape" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Valider">
        <?php
     } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to use a method of indexing fields, to identify which form each field belongs to.

Comment: example: `name="NomEtape"` need to ve ouput has  `name="NomEtape_1"`

Comment: dynamicaly you can receive it in php with `${'NomEtape_'.$countforms}`

Comment: It should be `$_POST['NomEtape_' . $countforms]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h3>Insertion des étape :</h3>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="5"> 
    <div id="formcontainer">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#quantity").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
            var count = $('#quantity').val();
            var htmlf = '';
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                htmlf += "<h5>Nom de l'étape</h5><br/>";
                htmlf += '<input type="text" name="NomEtape_"'+i+' size="40" maxlength="40">';
                htmlf += "<h5>Description de l'étape</h5><br/>";
                htmlf += '<textarea name="DescriptionEtape_"'+i+' rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>';
                htmlf += "<br/>"
            }
            $("#formcontainer").html(htmlf);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Simple Just run the code and you can find yourself easy.

Answer (score 0):

Right so it sounds like you want this form to update on page. For this you'll need to use JavaScript. PHP runs server side only, you want this to update on the client side.

Here is a quick example to get you on the right path. I am using jQuery which is a popular Javascript library.

```js
var $group = $('form .group').clone();
$('[name="quantity"]').on('change input keyup cut paste', function() {
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $('form .group').remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    $group.clone().insertBefore('form [type="submit"]');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Insertion des étape :</h3>

<form action="InsertionEtape.php" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="5">
  <br>
  <div class="group">
    <h5>Nom de l'étape</h5>
    <input type="text" name="NomEtape[]" size="40" maxlength="40">
    <br>

    <h5> Description de l'étape </h5>
    <textarea name="DescriptionEtape[]" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Valider">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

okey I changed to this but an error appeared,

```php
<form action="InsertionEtape.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    <br>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $_GET['quantity']; $i++) {

       echo "<h5>Nom de l'étape</h5>";
       echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"NomEtape_".$i."\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"40\"> <br>";
       ?>
        <h5> Description de l'étape </h5>
        <textarea name="DescriptionEtape" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Valider">
        <?php
     } ?>
</form>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: quantity in /***/**********/*****/******/WWW/Page_Administrateur/FormulaireInsertion.php on line 106

Comment: Do you have a `quantity` parameter in the URL you used to display the form?

Comment: `$_GET['quantity']` means that the URL needs to end with `?quantity=X`

Comment: Are you trying to use the value they entered into `<input name="quantity">`? That will be in `$_POST['quantity']`, but not until after they submit the form.

Comment: If you want to change the form immediately, without them submitting it, you need to do that in JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Quantity is in my code just hover the PHP ```HTML input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"```I want to enter a number in this input and then multiple forms to appear under

Comment: I nerver touched java script how can I do ?

Comment: Please both STOP solving issues on a Not an Answer use the question instead